# Storing nested structs on heap vs stack

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out the difference between structs on the heap and on the stack. I have the following structs, for Book, Author and Shelf. Book has multiple authors and Shelf has multiple books.

```
struct Author {
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
};

struct Book {
    char title[TITLE_LENGTH];
    struct Author authors[AUTHORS_PER_BOOK];
    int author_count;
};

struct Shelf {
    struct Book books[BOOKS_PER_SHELF];
    int book_count;
};
```

I have a bunch of functions of creating the Author and Book structs, with specified name and title. And a function for adding authors to book. I understand that C is strictly pass by value, so I used a pointer to the book in add_authors_to_book function. These functions are created locally, I am assuming they are on the stack(?).

```
struct Author new_author(char name[]) {
    struct Author author;
    strcpy(author.name, name);

    return author;
}

struct Book new_book(char title[]) {
    struct Book book;
    strcpy(book.title, title);

    book.author_count = 0;

    return book;
}

void print_book(struct Book book) {
    printf("%s\nby", book.title);
    int i, n;
    for (i = 0, n = book.author_count; i < n; i++) {
        printf(" %s,", book.authors[i].name);
    }

    printf("\b.\n");
}

void add_author_to_book(struct Book *book, struct Author author) {
    book->authors[book->author_count] = author;
    book->author_count++;
}
```

I want the shelf to be on the heap. I am allocating memory for it and freeing it below.

```
struct Shelf *new_shelf() {
    struct Shelf *shelf = malloc(sizeof(struct Shelf));
    shelf->book_count = 0;

    return shelf;
}

void delete_shelf(struct Shelf *shelf) {
    free(shelf);
}

void print_shelf(struct Shelf *shelf) {
    printf("Shelf has the %d book(s),\n", shelf->book_count);
    int i, n;
    for (i = 0, n = shelf->book_count; i < n; i++) {
        print_book(shelf->books[i]);
    }
}
```

> > My question is regarding adding the books to the shelf. Below I am assigning the book struct to the shelf's book at it's last index. Where does this struct Book reside, on the Heap or on the Stack? Will C create clone of the entire Book structure including the authors automatically when passing it to the add_book_to_shelf? Does pass by value work with such nested structs?
> >
> > Also how do you go about freeing up the memory used by books and it's authors?

```
void add_book_to_shelf(struct Shelf *shelf, struct Book book) {
    shelf->books[shelf->book_count] = book;
    shelf->book_count++;
}
```

Here's my test code,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct Shelf *shelf = new_shelf();

    struct Book book = new_book("Freakonomics");
    add_author_to_book(&book, new_author("Stephen Dubner"));
    add_author_to_book(&book, new_author("Steven Levitt"));

    add_book_to_shelf(shelf, book);

    print_shelf(shelf);
    delete_shelf(shelf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying the book in add_book_to_shelf, which means it will be on the heap.

The book that you created in main will be on the stack, (since it is an automatic variable,) but in add_book_to_shelf the book is copied into the books array which is allocated as part of the shelf on the heap.

Comment: Thanks. So the book via the pass-by-value auto copying and assignment in add_author_to_book is on the heap. Do we have to free this memory manually, or would free(shelf) do this automatically?

Comment: the free of shelf will remove all the books contained from the heap since they are part of the shelf

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the book resides in the shelf itself. Since you declared the shelf struct to contain books directly, it contains the full space neccesary to store the books inside of it. So assigning the book to a shelf actually copies its values into the shelf. So if the shelf is on the stack, the book will be on the stack and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. But I want the shelf on the heap, not the stack. I am using malloc to do this manually... Confused...

Comment: Ah! of I see what you meant. Both ways would work, book is inside shelf. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your use of free(),
just free(shelf) will be fine for your test code. shelf is a pointer whose data was dynamically allocated to the heap, and that is why it needs to be removed using free(). You don't have to use free(shelf->books[i]) because you did not dynamically allocate the books array. You declare BOOKS_PER_SHELF elements in the array automatically. This may not be efficient for memory management, but it makes your de-allocation very simple and readable.